# How to skip a field in Firestore when updating a document?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have `@ServerTimestamp var product_added_date: Date? = null,` in my model data class in Kotlin. When I update the product, later on, the value of `product_added_date` gets updated. I want to skip this field whenever I update the document. How can I do that? I googled for this but I couldn't find it.

Edit:

Following is the code I use to update the details.

```
    fun updateProduct(activity: ProductActivity, productDetails: Product, productId: String) {
    mFireStore.collection(Constants.PRODUCTS)
        .document(productId)
        .set(productDetails, SetOptions.merge())
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            activity.updatingProductSuccess()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            activity.hideProgressDialog()
        }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that you are using to perform the update.

Comment: @AlexMamo Code added in the question.

Comment: Please show what the object `productDetails` contains. If it contains your `product_added_date` field then it will overwrite it and you'd have to either remove it or manually specify which fields you'd like to update

Comment: @Hydra I have not provided any value for `product_added_date` In the `productDetails`. Since I have used the annotation in my model class it automatically adds to the Firestore every time I add a new product or update a product. I cannot specify which field I want to update as there are too many fields that I want to update but there are only 1 or 2 fields I do not want to update. Is there any option to skip (exclude) just one field from it being updated?

Comment: What is the type of the `productDetails` object?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to perform a partial update when you pass a Java class to the `set()` method - as Firestore has no way of knowing which fields you want to update and which ones you don't.

When you want to perform a partial update, put the fields you want to update in a `Map<String,Object>` and pass that to `.set(map, SetOptions.merge())`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, In my case, I have more than a hundred fields that need to be updated and only one field that needs to be skipped from being updated, so I thought it would be better to use an option to skip one field if such an option exists at all, rather than creating `mapOf` where I have to mention all the field names. But, when I try to do it the way you have suggested, I have one problem that I do not know if I can add ServerTimestamp to one of my fields. Is it possible to add ServerTimestamp when I use `mapOf`?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. If you're having trouble making it work, I recommend posting a new question about it with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can update specific field via use mapOf in kotlin
as this

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(productId).set(mapOf(
    "key1" to "string value",
    "key2" to "int Value",
    "name" to productDetails.name,
    "price" to productDetails.price,
    "key5" to "Any Value"
),SetOptions.merge())
```

Change all key string to your key for product object in firestore
and set any value.